# SimpleHTTPServer Error 404 - "GET /d3/d3.v3.js HTTP/1.1" 404

Tags: javascript, d3.js, localserver

I am learning D3 and I am trying to set up a local server on a mac machine to host a webpage. I follow these steps

1. Set up the local server using: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`
2. Access the index file using: `http://localhost:8888`

Here are the problems I am facing.

- When I try step 2 I get the following messages on terminal

  ```
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014 12:14:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014 12:14:52] code 404, message File not found
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014 12:14:52] "GET /d3/d3.v3.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014 12:14:53] code 404, message File not found
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014 12:14:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
  ```
- When I open the index file directly it does not open via the local
  web server and instead opens with the following address
  "file://.../Users/d3_book/index.html"
  Here is the code (without the html tags) for my index file

  ```
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>D3 Page Template</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          // D3 code will go here
      </script>
  </body>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your d3 files are in `"../d3/d3.v3.js"` but the server is looking for them in `/d3/d3.v3.js`. Perhaps that could be the source of the error?

The web server might not be able to access files outside of the directory that it was started in.

Comment: You are right. I figured it out myself just now. There were a couple of errors. The correct path is `/d3/d3.js` instead of `../d3/d3.v3.js`. I am still unable to open the webpage directly by clicking on it. I have to specify the path via the local host. Which I guess is fine for now. Though I wonder if there is an obvious solution that my novice brain is missing.

Comment: Do you mean you can't open the `index.html` file by double clicking it? You won't be able to do that and have it run on the server, you'd have to go to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`.

Comment: Of course. D3 is an awesome framework, have fun with it.